# enumerate resource-bundles defined in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf-2, resourcebundle, faces-config

I am using a mojarra-specific code for this:

```
public static Map<String, ResourceBundle> getBundleMap()
{
    Locale locale = Faces.getLocale();

    ApplicationAssociate associate = ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, ApplicationResourceBundle> resourceBundles = associate.getResourceBundles();

    Map<String, ResourceBundle> map = new HashMap<>(resourceBundles.size());
    for(Entry<String, ApplicationResourceBundle> entry : resourceBundles.entrySet())
    {
        String name = entry.getKey();
        ResourceBundle bundle = entry.getValue().getResourceBundle(locale);

        map.put(name, bundle);
    }

    return map;
}
```

I'd like to have an implementation-agnostic way to get this map.

Should I parse every `faces-config.xml` defined in application and libs? Isn't this reinventing the wheel?

A `Map<String, String>`, where `key = /faces-config/application/resource-bundle/var` and `value = /faces-config/application/resource-bundle/base-name` would be sufficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'd like to have an implementation-agnostic way to get this map.*

Understandable.

---

> *Should I parse every faces-config.xml defined in application and libs?*

Yes. This functionality isn't available in JSF API.

---

> *Isn't this reinventing the wheel?*

Yes, definitely. You could however try to get it into [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), which has already a similar utility class for `/WEB-INF/web.xml` and all `/META-INF/web-fragment.xml`, the [`WebXml`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/WebXml).

---

> *A `Map<String, String>`, where key = `/faces-config/application/resource-bundle/var` and value = `/faces-config/application/resource-bundle/base-name` would be sufficient.*

Here's a kickoff example using JAXP (*cough*):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();
document.appendChild(document.createElement("all-faces-configs"));

List<URL> facesConfigURLs = new ArrayList<>();
facesConfigURLs.add(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml"));
facesConfigURLs.addAll(Collections.list(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/faces-config.xml")));

for (URL facesConfigURL : facesConfigURLs) {
    URLConnection connection = facesConfigURL.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    try (InputStream input = connection.getInputStream()) {
        NodeList children = builder.parse(input).getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.importNode(children.item(i), true));
        }
    }
}

Map<String, String> resourceBundles = new HashMap<>();
Element allFacesConfigs = document.getDocumentElement();
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList resourceBundleNodes = (NodeList) xpath.compile("application/resource-bundle").evaluate(allFacesConfigs, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < resourceBundleNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node resourceBundleNode = resourceBundleNodes.item(i);
    String var = xpath.compile("var").evaluate(resourceBundleNode).trim();
    String baseName = xpath.compile("base-name").evaluate(resourceBundleNode).trim();
    resourceBundles.put(var, baseName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as usual :) I implemented `FacesConfigXml` on the base of `WebXml`. How can I try to get it into OmniFaces? Should I open an issue?

Comment: Yes. Or a pull request. But I'd have to refactor it with `WebXml` anyway.

Comment: OK, done a pull request. Never used GIT before, amazing!